# Deciding if a molecule is polar and non-polar in cyclic carbon compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, hybridization, polarity, dipole

While discussing about dipole moment of the compounds, our chemistry teacher told that the dipole moment will be 0 for 1,4-Dichlorobenzen, and for those compounds where same atoms or group of atoms are attached in para position if the hybridization of the atom of the group which is directly attached to the carbon of the benzene ring is sp or sp2 but if it is not the case i.e if OH is attached at para positions then the dipole moment wont be 0. I want to know if there is any reason or are they just unexplained examples. Are there more such exceptions?
Please check the picture for examples.[image]

Comment: Yes there is a reason, **symmetry**.

Comment: No but if the copound is oh instead of no2 the hybridisation will be sp3 and dipole moment wont be 0

Comment: Exactly, because it won't be **symmetrical**. Is the OH going to be linear?

Comment: Ok then why true for no2. It has lone pairs more towards doubly bonded oxygen

Comment: Resonance, both the oxygens are the same

Comment: Oh yes. But in OH attached to C why the dipole moment wont be 0 why the O and H and C are in the same plane and lone pairs are invisible

Comment: @avnish can you tell that instead of OH if CH3 was on either side , what would have been the dipole moment?

Comment: Both sides or one

Comment: On Both the sides CH3 there on opposite vertices. My teacher said that the dipole moment will not be 0 I can't understand why. Do you have the same opinion?

Comment: The dipole moment **is** 0 see [this](http://www.stenutz.eu/chem/solv6.php?name=p-xylene)

Comment: The actual reason behind sp3 atoms if its not CH3 type structure meaning all visible 4 'equivalent'bonds having dipole moment not equal to 0 is the exsistance of infinite conformers for the same molecule out of which only one is 0 and rest are not. The reason why only sp3 shows such variation is tgat sp2 hybridized or single atom or sp hybridized atoms would be equally planar on both tge sided so as to cancel dipole moment of each other in all possible ways meaning for every conformer there is a counter conformer so the final dipole moment is 0.